# Is this floating ship really a mirage?

Tags: optics, temperature, refraction

The media is full of stories of rare pictures of flying ships. They go on to describe them as mirages. These images are described as rare. The picture I have uploaded was taken on Good Friday 2022 from Port Lympne Safari Park near Folkestone in Kent UK. Here we see what looks like a ship floating in the air well above the horizon. I have not altered the photograph in any way. It was taken using my Nikon P1000. I always believed that such pictures were mirages until reading an interesting article debunking the idea. The article explains that the sea is immediately below the vessel, it just happens to be the same or similar colour as the sky. The sea can vary in colour according to sun light, sea depth and weather conditions and is not always a uniform colour all the way to the horizon. What do the physics experts think, are the floating / flying ship pictures really mirages?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/704412/2451

Comment: Hi Mark Allen. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps you will kindly sort it out for me as I find this site extremely difficult to use

Comment: The link provided by QMechanic in your last post explains how this happens: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619022/