What is the line of sight distance across the ocean?
I just watched an experiment where they had a laser at a height of 50 feet (15 metre) above sea level and were able to see it 23 miles (37 km) away at a receiver which was 20 feet (6 metre) above sea level. According to this chart:
http://www.totally-cuckoo.com/distance_visible_to_the_horizon.htm
It says the distance to the horizon at 50 feet (15 metre) is 9.35 miles (15 km) and the distance at 20 feet (6 metre) is 5.92 miles (9.5 km). That's 15.27 miles (24.6 km) total so how was the laser seen at 23 miles (37 km)? Even with a refraction rate of 8% that's only 1.84 miles (3.0 km) for a total of 17.11 miles (27.5 km). So how was the laser seen at 23 miles (37 km)? What am I missing here?

Likely they are not reporting the elevation accurately, but you didn't provide a reference to the experiment so no one can say anything about it.

The effects of atmospheric refraction vary with the weather, especially near the horizon, and can sometimes be quite strong, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619022/123208

I don't see what is not clear about this question. The OP has noted a discrepancy and seeks an explanation. The salient facts are there. Voting to reopen. To the op. Perhaps add anything else you can remember about the experiment and how you calculated the refraction rate.

@KDP OP has noted a discrepancy but we don't know what the discrepancy is save for their assurance that the experiment was exactly right. We do need that context to actually say anything about the experiment. Otherwise we are still left to guess as to the discrepancy.
